# Ошибка при изменении модуля. Joomla

Tags: javascript, cms, joomla

Пытаюсь изменить текст: выдает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При поиске решения данной проблемы рекомендуют изменить размер содержимого модуля, кто сталкивался с похожей проблемой?

Comment: Интересно, что вы пытаетесь запихнуть в этот редактор? Уверен  пробуете установить очень длинный текст или нестандартный HTML структуру ? Данная ошибка выбрасывается т.к обработчие не успевает обработать все данные из редактора, однако, по стандарту лимит большой, а значит что вы что то большое хотие сохранить, что это?

Comment: @Arsen просто пытаюсь изменить одну букву, или стереть хочу, все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: т.е если удалить всё содержимое в редакторе и сохранить, так же выдаёт ошибку? Если да, то проблема в редакторе, какой редактор установлен? в настройках Joomla установите другой редактор и проверьте работоспособность.